# Full page image

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate a page i'd be given but cleaning the css. I don't understand why on the original page the first image is fully shown while in mine not. CSS to me seems the same. This is the page snippet

```
<section id="mega-img">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>title</h1>

    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
<div class="big-bg"></div>
```

and this the related css. Web site uses bootstrap as main styling tool

```
#mega-img {
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5em 0 3em 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-img .inner {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#330000, endColorstr=#330000);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#330000, endColorstr=#330000)";
}
#mega-img .inner h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.8em;
  font-size: 4em;
}
#mega-img .inner p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.big-bg {
  background-image: url(../images/photo/foto_big_home.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Where am I wrong?

[This is my page](http://www.daisyclick.com/_tiziano/test.html)

[This is the original page](http://www.daisyclick.com/_tiziano/test2.html)

they're the same page with only CSS change. I'd like that my page display a full image as the original one.

Comment: your original page has `html,body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: since someone just answered with the same answer, let me know if this works and if you like, I can move it to an answer and you can accept it.

Comment: Yes, as said it works. Since you answered first i'll mark yours as the answer if you make it as an answer. By the way, i'd like to understand why this happen

Comment: Because if element A contains element B and A is smaller than 100%, B _can't_ be 100%. If I am 6 feet tall, and I'm a pregnant woman, I can't have a baby that's taller than 6 feet. And for full disclosure, I'm not a woman, I'm not pregnant, and I'm taller than 6 feet.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @TizianoMischi select an answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original page has `html,body { height: 100%; }`. Add that to the new site, and then `#mega-img { height: 100%; }` will have something to grow into.

Check out this video for a good explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hExwnLlj2xk

Comment: recommend this answer

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have removed the html, and body height in your new stylesheet. The original site declares the body and html to be 100%, try re-adding that back into your css. Let me know if you need a jfiddle for it. :)

Comment: yes! that's the answer. Now i'd like to understand why the height 100% has to be applied to the html and the body in order to allow a 100% on a div inside it

Comment: We need to tell the browser window as to what height it will become 100% of basically.